# Null values when reading remote object from java POJO using BlazeDS and Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I'm not getting any errors when I run the following files, but the data returned from the Java POJO object coming from the trace() statements below is:

```
[object ComputerInfo]
null
[object ComputerInfo]
null
```

and I'm out of ideas how to debug this. I've tried to adapt the code taken [from here](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-java/developer-den/technical-articles/flex-java-development.html).

My client files are as follows. My mxml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;

        private var reqId1:int = 0;

        public var dataReadFromDB:ComputerInfo = new ComputerInfo;

        private function readFaultHandler( event:FaultEvent ):void 
        {
            Alert.show( event.fault.faultString, "Error reading data" ); 
        }

        private function readResultHandler( event:ResultEvent ):void
        { 
            dataReadFromDB.javaVersion = event.result.javaVersion; 
            dataReadFromDB.javaVendor = event.result.javaVendor; 
            dataReadFromDB.os = event.result.os; 
            dataReadFromDB.osVersion = event.result.osVersion; 
            dataReadFromDB.requestId = event.result.requestId; 
            trace(dataReadFromDB);
            trace(dataReadFromDB.javaVersion); 
            trace(event.result);
            trace(event.result.javaVersion);
        } 

    ]]></fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations> 
        <mx:RemoteObject 
            id="ro" 
            destination="myDestination"
            showBusyCursor="true">
            <mx:method name="readData" 
                      result="readResultHandler(event);"  
                      fault="readFaultHandler(event);"/>
        </mx:RemoteObject>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:Panel width="476" height="281" 
              layout="absolute" title="BlazeDS Example" 
              cornerRadius="0" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
        <s:Label x="46" y="59" text="Click to Read Data" />
        <s:Button x="200" y="59"  label="Read Now"   click="ro.readData( reqId1++ )"/>
    </mx:Panel> 
</s:Application>
```

ComputerInfo.as file:

```
package {
    [RemoteClass(alias="ComputerInfo")]
     public class ComputerInfo {
        public var javaVersion:String;
        public var javaVendor:String;
        public var os:String;
        public var osVersion:String;
        public var requestId:String;
    }
}
```

My java files are:

```
public class MyClass {
    public ComputerInfo readData( String requestId ) {
            ComputerInfo computerInfo = new ComputerInfo();
            computerInfo.javaVersion = "java.vm.version";
            computerInfo.javaVendor = "java.vm.vendor";
            computerInfo.os = "osname";
            computerInfo.osVersion = "os.version";
            computerInfo.requestId = "requestId";
            return computerInfo;
    }
}
```

and a separate file called ComputerInfo.java:

```
public class ComputerInfo {
    String javaVersion;
    String javaVendor;
    String os;
    String osVersion;
    String requestId;
}
```

Inside remoting-config.xml:

```
<destination id="myDestination">
            <properties>
                    <source>myClass</source>
            </properties>
</destination>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the [RemoteClass] meta tags in your data transfer object (ComputerInfo.as):

```
package {
    [RemoteClass(alias="com.myjavapackage.ComputerInfo")]
    public class ComputerInfo { ... }
}
```

(where you'd have to replace "com.myjavapackage" with the appropriate values; the package was not mentioned in your code samples)

If the tags are missing, Flex won't be able to deserialize the data into the appropriate type, and you get an object of type "ObjectProxy" instead.

You can also remove your own copying of the result values - `event.result` will already be of type `ComputerInfo`, if everything is registered correctly.

**EDIT**

Also, your the field variables in your Java class should be `public`, or there should be `public` getter and setter methods.

For more info, see the [Adobe Doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html#202412). The relevant section is "Explicitly mapping ActionScript and Java objects".

Comment: I edited the original posting above to include the [RemoteClass(...)] line but it still results in undefined output from the trace commands (as shown above). I'm sure this helped, but something still not quite right. The ComputerInfo.class sits in the WEB-INF/classes folder on the server, and the ComputerInfo.as sits in same folder as the mxml file in FlashBuilder. I made sure to Clean to recompile everything.

Comment: Works great now!!! Follow-up's: (1) Is [Bindable] needed just above [RemoteClass(...)] in ComputerInfo.as? The Adobe doc shows it there. (2) Should variable declarations in ComputerInfo.as also be `public`? (or is this set that way by default?)

Comment: 1) No, `[Bindable]` is optional.  2) Yes, they must be `public`. The default namespace is `internal`.

Comment: Thank you weltraumpirat. You saved me (again). For reference, the modifications I made to the above posting to get it to work were: (1) change variable declarations to public in ComputerInfo.java, (2) added [RemoteClass(...)] to ComputerInfo.as, and (3) add the following to `readResultHandler()` function declaration, on the first line after the opening curly bracket (i.e. "{"): `dataReadFromDB=event.result as ComputerInfo;`

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to your BlazeDS question (weltraumpirat has already answered it quite well), you could also consider using [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org) and its code generation tools (see documentation [here](http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.gas3.html)): you wouldn't have anymore to write by hands your AS3 classes and all your Java fields, including private/protected ones, would be serialized (though an *opaque* Java field, ie. declared private with no getter/setter, would remain *opaque* in the generated AS3 class).